Did Holden Caulfield starve himself for two entire weeks?
At the start of chapter 15, Holden says:

The last time I’d eaten was those two hamburgers I had with Brossard and Ackley when we went in to Agerstown to the movies. That was a long time ago. It seemed like fifty years ago.

I thought that this was just Holden exaggerating the time of, like, two days, but then he says this, in the same chapter:

I’d check my bags in one of those strong boxes that they give you a key to, then get some breakfast. I was sort of hungry. While I was in the cab, I took out my wallet and sort of counted my money. I don’t remember exactly what I had left, but it was no fortune or anything. I’d spent a king’s ransom in about two lousy weeks.

There are two possibilities. One is that Holden is exaggerating again, but this time it's for his own thoughts' benefit (minzaggerating?), which is the opposite direction of the cynical remarks he's made about himself over the course of the book so far. So, the other possibility... is that he really did not eat anything since he left Pennsylvania? Am I missing an important cue here?

It seems safe to presume that the two weeks is either also an exaggeration or that the statement refers to money spent prior to the beginning of the novel: the action in Catcher in the Rye largely takes place over a period of days. In this instance, it appears that Holden has not eaten for something like thirty-six hours.
Agerstown is a fictional place, but we know it's located in Pennsylvania. While Pennsylvania is a large state, some of it borders New York: travelling from New York to Philadelphia, Pennsylvania's most populous city, takes a couple of hours, so it's entirely reasonable to presume the journey between Agerstown and New York is not long. In fact, Holden takes it several times in the course of the novel, so it cannot be a major commute.
Consider the timeline of events. Holden starts out in Agerstown and travels to New York for a fencing match. He returns that same afternoon - which is why we can be certain that it's situated fairly close to New York. Having done so, he goes to town and eats with Brossard and Ackley.
Later that night - or early in the following morning - he travels back to New York, where he checks into a hotel. It seems like he does not, however, sleep until that evening and the action you quote at the start of chapter 15 occurs after he wakes the following morning.
So: he eats one evening, spends the next day in New York, and wakes up the following morning hungry. That's around a day and a half without food, which would seem entirely plausible for someone of Holden's age.
